# Angular formly - Element focus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

I have a wrapper to my fields that transform a normal text to an input when mouse over, i Also has a directory that sets focus on that field when it opens.

Now i want the field to stay open as long as i have focus on that field and transform back to a normal text if focus becomes false. Is there a good way to do this?

[I have a bin of what i got at the moment.](http://jsbin.com/ninaqegoce/1/edit?js,output)

Wrapper:

```
template: [
                '<div ng-hide="to.editorEnabled" >',
                    '<div ng-mouseover="to.editorEnabled=true">',
                        '{{to.label}}</br>',
                        '{{to.value}}',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div focus-me="to.editorEnabled" ng-show="to.editorEnabled">',
                    '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
                '</div>'
            ].join(' ')
```

Focus directive:

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        console.log('value=',value);
        if(value === true) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].firstElementChild.focus(); 
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Formly field:

```
key: 'textField',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Text',
          type: 'text',
          value:vm.model.textField
        },
        watcher: {
          listener: function(field, newValue, oldValue, scope, stopWatching) {
            if(newValue) {
              if(!newValue || newValue === "") {
                field.templateOptions.value = "Undefined";
              }
              else {
                field.templateOptions.value = newValue;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In formly you can add onBlur and onFocus in templateOptions. So you can add a variable called `focused`, and onBlur set it to `false` and onFocus set it to `true`.

```
templateOptions: {
      onBlur:'to.focused=false',
      onFocus:'to.focused=true',
      focused:'true'
},
```

In the directive added two scope variables `model` and `fucus`. There `model` is the variable you called `to.editorEnabled` and `focus` will be the new created variable `to.focused`.

```
scope: {
        model:'=',
        focus:'='
}
```

And later on your directive you can add a extra watcher for the `focused` variable. 
`scope.$watch("focus", function(value) {
       if(!scope.focus){
          scope.model=false;
       }
});`
So if focus is losted, it set the `scope.model` to false, which make the input disappear.

Also made a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xicudakuru/edit?js,console,output) so you can take a closer look at it.

Hope this was what you was looking for.